# How to migrate from Git-Annex to Git LFS

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs, git-annex

How can I migrate a repository in which I'm managing large files with Git-annex to manage them with Git LFS?

Which commands should I run to disable annex and enable LFS?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a little bit, I've found the answer for this equation!

We need to change annex mode to `direct` first, then `git annex uninit`, then change the mode back to `indirect`, then add, commit and push.

```
$ git annex direct
$ git annex uninit
$ git annex indirect
# add, commit and push
# track with LFS (per file, extension, or folder)
$ git lfs track images/*
```

I'm working on a migration guide that will be available soon (I'll link it here).

UPDATE: Here it is :) https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/lfs/migrate_from_git_annex_to_git_lfs.html